# Force to use specific ES version

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, eslint

I have some files that will be handled with Babel and therefore are written in ES6. However, I also have some files that will not go through Babel and there fore should be in ES5 in the same project. Can I configure Eslint so it would throw errors, if I accidentally use some ES6 features (e.g. arrow functions, destructuring) in those files?

I've noticed, that setting `"parserOptions": {"ecmaVersion": 5}` doesn't provide desirable effect as well as setting `"env": {"es6": false}`.

Comment: Do you have problems distinguishing the files (you mention that you have both) or just problems with making it lint them according to ES5?

Comment: @Bergi, no, files are separated to different folders. So I can easily place different `.eslintrc` there. The problem is - what I have to write in that `.eslintrc` to forbid use of es6 syntax.

Comment: Sounds to me that having a separate `.eslintrc` file with `"parserOptions": {"ecmaVersion": 5}` should work. You said *"doesn't provide desirable effect"*, does it have any effect at all?

Answer (score 2):

As it finally turned out, the problem was in shareable config that I used ([xo](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-config-xo)). In that config `ecmaVersion` was set to 6, and [ESLint doesn't support override for ecmaVersion](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-config-xo/issues/16#issuecomment-190302577)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Disabling Rules with Inline Comments

```
/* eslint-disable */
    alert('foo');
/* eslint-enable */
```

Also take a look at http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: There is no problem to disable rules. I'm just wondering if there are some rules that forbid es6 stuff (preferable - one rule to forbid all new stuff).

Comment: you can use jshint with parametr  "esversion" : 6

Answer (score 0):

I had `sourceType: "module"` in my config.  I think this was forcing eslint into ES6 mode.

```
parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 5,
  sourceType: "module",
},
```

When I remove that `sourceType` then eslint did start warning about inappropriate use of ES6 syntax.

(Although that was often from actual parsing errors rather than linter rules!)

If you have inherited `sourceType` from another config then you could try overriding it, but I don't know what the default (ES5) value is.